# Avoid stripping markup

Tags: jquery, orphan

This script is driving me crazy, its main feature is to avoid orphans on long headings.

Everything worked well until I realized that if I added any sort of markup to the `<h1>` (an `<a href="#">` in this case), the markup gets stripped out, hence, the link is lost.

This is the current script:

```
$('h1').each(function() {
  var wordArray = $(this).text().split(' ');
  if (wordArray.length > 1) {
    wordArray[wordArray.length-2] += '&nbsp;' + wordArray[wordArray.length-1];
    wordArray.pop();
    $(this).html(wordArray.join(' '));
  }
});
```

Here's a [**simple demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FbRZk/11/).

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your usage of the `.text()` function to get the content of the header. That automatically strips out any markup, returning only the text nodes. What you need to do is get the HTML (use `.html()` rather than `.text()`) then check for the presence of closing tags at the end of the last word to append back to the new content for your header element:

```
$('h1').each(function() {
    var wordArray = $(this).html().split(' ');
    if (wordArray.length > 1) {
        wordArray[wordArray.length-2] += '&nbsp;' + wordArray[wordArray.length-1];

        var lastWord = wordArray.pop();
        lastWord = lastWord.replace(/.*((?:<\/\w+>)*)$/, '$1');
        $(this).html(wordArray.join(' ') + lastWord);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FbRZk/12/)

Comment: `.html()`, got it. This worked flawlessly. What's difficult for me with JavaScript is the abstractions like the one you just explained, but I'm getting there. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).html(wordArray.join(' '));  //Line causing the issue.
```

Since your replacing the entire `html` inside `h1` the hyperlink is vanished.

So instead of targeting `h1`, change the script to handle the `a` tag like below

```
$('h1 a').each(function() {
  var wordArray = $(this).text().split(' ');
  if (wordArray.length > 1) {
    wordArray[wordArray.length-2] += '&nbsp;' + wordArray[wordArray.length-1];
    wordArray.pop();
    $(this).html(wordArray.join(' '));
  }
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FbRZk/9/)

Comment: That assumes that they never want to call it on a heading that doesn't include an anchor, and that the entire text of the heading is contained within the anchor element.

Comment: Well, that was kind of easy :). However, if you add any other type of markup in there it also gets stripped out, for example the `<span>` here gets taken out: `<h1><a href="#">Looong heading <span>that</span> could end up with orphans...</a></h1>`. I've tried adding another selector like `$('h1 a, h1 a span')` or even a global selector `$('h1 *')` but even with this global selector although the `<a href="">` is kept, the `<span>` is stripped. Any idea why? Man, this script is SO close to being the perfect solution. Updated **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FbRZk/13/)**. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, You're right, what if we have headings both with links and without links? And also with inline markup as well as I describe again above? This script should account for that as well. But the question is 'How'? I think this script is almost there.

Comment: @Ricardo I already posted an answer that addresses all of those issues.